# Windows ignores which interface to use in routing table

Tags: networking, windows-7, routing, local-area-network, gateway

Hi i'm running windows 7 and i have 2 network cards, one wireless with internet connection and one wired with local lan connection.
I want to use both at the same time so i set the lan card to 1st place in interface priority list and manually set lower metric to the wireless card so that gateway will be preferred.

Then i added a route "route add 172.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 172.21.61.161 metric 1 if 11"
This is my local network with 172.21.61.161 as gateway and 255.255.255.224 is the submask for this network.

The wireless network is automatically configured to 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 with the wireless gateway and interface set.

Both local connection and internet works this way, BUT the local network is really slow so i sniffed the wireless card using wireshark while connecting and browsing "\ \LANPCNAME" and saw that windows is trying to find every local path via the wireless interface first, HOW CAN I MAKE IT UNDERSTAND THAT I ONLY WANT TO USE INTERFACE 11 FOR THIS ROUTE???

One thing i've noticed is that if i connect to another wireless network and try to connect the local computer it takes about 10 seconds to connect and then it works as i want to, probably the wireless card times out and windows decides to use the local adapter instead.

The wireless network that isn't working is a domain work network....

I really appreciate any help!

Here's a "route print" translated to english:

```
===========================================================================

Interface list
11...38 ea a7 5d 95 34 ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
12...60 67 20 95 a6 bc ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
===========================================================================
Routes for IPv4
===========================================================================
Active routes:

Network address          Submask   Gateway-address      Interface    Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.211.128.2   10.211.128.255     460
 10.211.128.0    255.255.240.0         Vid lan    10.211.128.255     476
10.211.128.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan    10.211.128.255    476
10.211.143.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan    10.211.128.255    476
    127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         Vid lan       127.0.0.1       306
    127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         Vid lan       127.0.0.1       306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan     127.0.0.1       306
    172.0.0.0        255.0.0.0    172.21.61.161    172.21.61.173     241
   172.21.0.0  255.255.255.224    172.21.61.161    172.21.61.173     243
  172.21.61.0    255.255.255.0    172.21.61.161    172.21.61.173     440
172.21.61.160  255.255.255.224         Vid lan     172.21.61.173     496
172.21.61.173  255.255.255.255         Vid lan     172.21.61.173     496
172.21.61.191  255.255.255.255         Vid lan     172.21.61.173     496
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         Vid lan         127.0.0.1     306
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         Vid lan     172.21.61.173     496
    224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         Vid lan    10.211.128.255     476
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan      127.0.0.1      306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan     172.21.61.173   496
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         Vid lan    10.211.128.255   476
====== ======== =================== =======================================
Static routes:
Network address         Submask    Gateway address   Metric
    172.0.0.0        255.0.0.0    172.21.61.161       1
===========================================================================
Routes for IPv6
===========================================================================
Active routes:
Gr Mått   Nätverk Mål              Gateway
1    306 ::1/128                  Vid lan
1    306 ff00::/8                 Vid lan
===========================================================================
Static routes:
None
```

ipconfig:

```
Ethernet-anslutning Local Area Connection:

   Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . :
   IPv4-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.61.173
   Nätmask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
   Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . :

Trådlös anslutning Wireless Network Connection:

   Anslutningsspecifika DNS-suffix . : secret.server.com
   IPv4-adress . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.211.128.255
   Nätmask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Standard-gateway. . . . . . . . . : 10.211.128.2
```

Comment: Please include the output of `ipconfig` in your question.

Comment: Ipconfig is now added

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED IT!!

My drive was mapped with "\computername\share" which means that it will look for "computername" in the default gateway's subnet, right? When i mapped the drive with "\172.x.x.x\share" it worked! Of course without default gateway and the static route "route add 172.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 172.21.61.161 metric 1 if 11"

I can't belive that i missed such an obvious thing....

Comment: We all missed 'obvious things' every now and then... shows how important a checklist is :) ... glad you have it solved.

Comment: Yeah i guess... :) I mapped this drive a long time ago when i was only using one network so it took me a while to realize what was wrong.